# Using Salesforce as IDP for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, salesforce

I have a asp.net website. I am going to post a link to this website in SalesForce. Our requirement is that any user who has logged into SalesForce should get logged into the custom web site when he clicks on the the link.

Is it technically possible to even do this ?

Answer (score 1):

[Yes.](https://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/identity_provider_about.htm)

Comment: Could you please clarify on you response ?